# getting specific selected text from md-select when the option has many keys

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I have this array of objects:

```json
[
     {
          name: "Dubai",
          transformed_cost: 50,
          delivery_time: 30
     },
     {
          name: "Abu Dhabi",
          transformed_cost: 15,
          delivery_time: 7
     },
     {
          name: "Shariqah",
          transformed_cost: 50,
          delivery_time: 4
     }
]
```

I'm using this array inside `md-select` as following:

```html
<md-select ng-model='delivery_zone' md-selected-text="getSelectedText()">
    <md-optgroup label="Destinatios">
        <md-option ng-repeat='z in deliveryZones'>
            <div flex layout='row' layout-align="space-between" >
                <span>{{ z.name}}</span>
                <span>{{z.transformed_cost}} AED</span>
                <span style="display: block;">Delivery in: {{   z.delivery_time}}</span>
            </div>
        </md-option>
    </md-optgroup>
</md-select>
```

the `getSelectedText()` function I'm using:

```js
$scope.getSelectedText = function() {
    if ($scope.delivery_zone !== undefined) {
        return $scope.delivery_zone;
    }
    else {
        return "Please select a destenation";
    }
};
```

It returns the whole option as you can see here:
[image]

I need to print out inside the options just the **name** key (Dubai, Abu Dhabi) without transformed_cost and delivery_time.

How can I make it?

Comment: Hi I have added the answer below please check, If you want anything else just comment below the answer so I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are missing `ng-value` for the `md-option` having `ng-repeat` hence we are getting the label being shown. The solution will be as follow.

First add `ng-value` to the `ng-option`.

```
<md-option ng-repeat='z in deliveryZones' ng-value="z">
```

Then you need to change the function to.

```
$scope.getSelectedText = function() {
    if ($scope.delivery_zone !== undefined) {
        return $scope.delivery_zone.name;
    }
    else {
        return "Please select a destenation";
    }
};
```

here is a demo for the same!

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

I would like to comment that, you don't need the function itself, You can just write it as.

```
<div ng-app='home' ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <md-select ng-model='delivery_zone' md-selected-text="delivery_zone()">
    <md-optgroup label="Destinatios">
      <md-option ng-repeat='z in deliveryZones'>
        <div flex layout='row' layout-align="space-between">
          <span>{{ z.name}}</span>
          <span>{{z.transformed_cost}} AED</span>
          <span style="display: block;">Delivery in: {{   z.delivery_time}}</span>
        </div>
      </md-option>
    </md-optgroup>
  </md-select>
</div>
```

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<md-select ng-model='delivery_zone'>
  <md-optgroup label="Destinatios">
    <md-option ng-value="opt" ng-repeat='opt in deliveryZones' ng-click="getSelectedText(opt)">
      <div flex layout='row' layout-align="space-between" >
        <span>{{ z.name}}</span>
        <span>{{z.transformed_cost}} AED</span>
        <span style="display: block;">Delivery in: {{   z.delivery_time}}</span>
      </div>
    </md-option>
  </md-optgroup>
</md-select>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.getSelectedText = function(selectedVal) {
    if (selectedVal !== undefined) {
        return selectedVal.name;
    }
    else {
        return "Please select a destenation";
    }
};
```

I've added opt variable in order to eliminate duplication. In addition to that I'm doing ng-click on particular option instead of ng-change on parent md-select, I hope this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can return simple name from your function like

```
return $scope.delivery_zone.name;
```